# Match specific line in Solr

Tags: solr

I have the following JSON indexed by Solr:

```
[{
    id: 'some-id',
    body: [
        {
            line_t: 'Some line in some text',
            lineNumber: 1
        },
        {
            line_t: 'Some other line in the same text',
            lineNumber: 2
        },
        ...
    ]
}, ...]
```

I want to highlight the search results, which I do by `hl=on&hl.snippets=1000&hl.fl=body.line_t`, but I would also like to know the acompanying lineNumbers.

The `response` shows the `id` and the entire `body`.

The `highlighting` shows only the highlighted `line_t`.

Is there a way to show `line_t` and the `lineNumber` in the `hightlighting`?

**UPDATE**

I've flattened my JSON and put the lineNumber with the `id`:

```
[{
    id: 'some-id___1',
    line_t: 'Some line in some text',
 },
 {
    id: 'some-id___2',
    line_t: 'Other line, same text',
 },
 ...
]
```

This way, I get the id, the line number and the highlighted text in the `highlighting` object. Is this the way to go about?

Is Solr capable of post processing (reducing|aggregating) the `highlighting` results?